# Defining glossary entries on the fly?

Tags: glossaries, preamble, xindy

I am using [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package and [Xindy](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/) to generate glossaries in Persian. Do I have to separately define the words to be included in the glossary?

I tried to define a command that defines the entry on the fly just when I want to show it in the document, but I got nothing, as xindy does not expand commands. This is a MWE, which prints what I intended, but does not show anything in the glossary. Maybe I should redefine `newglossaryentry`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\glos}[2]{%
\newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#2},description={#1}}#1\footnote{\Gls{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \glos{Latex language}{latex} typesetting markup language is
specially suitable for documents that include \glos{Mathematics}{math}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Is there any workarounds? I could be able to do the same thing with `\index` by defining:

```
\newcommand{\myidx}[1]{#1\index{#1}}
```

This is the list of commands I usually use to get output:

```
xelatex myfile
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -M texindy myfile.idx
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M myfile.xdy -t myfile.glg -o myfile.gls myfile.glo
xindy -L persian-variant1 -C utf8 -I xindy -M myfile.xdy -t myfile.blg -o myfile.bls myfile.blo
xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M myfile.xdy -t myfile.alg -o myfile.acr myfile.acn
xelatex myfile
xelatex myfile
```

Comment: If I use `\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}` and remove the useless `\maketitle` and run the  `makeglossaries` perl script after `pdflatex` I **do** have the entries, however, I am not using `xelatex` and `xepersian`

Comment: In addition: The `glossaries` documentation recommends the definition in the `preamble`, not in the body.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, the problem was the lack of [xindy] option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `xindy` it's necessary to say `\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}`.

This is the pipeline to follow (assuming the `.tex` file is called `foo.tex`)

> pdflatex foo
>
> makeglossaries foo
>
> pdflatex foo
>
> pdflatex foo % Perhaps a third run is necessary

However, it's not advised to define the glossary entries in the document body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


\newcommand{\glos}[2]{%
\newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#2},description={#1}}#1\footnote{\Gls{#2}}}

\begin{document}

The \glos{Latex language}{latex} typesetting markup language is
specially suitable for documents that include \glos{Mathematics}{math}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not define entries in the document body? It seems accessible for me. :-) Does it cause problems?

Comment: @Ho1: As long as you do not refer glossary entries before you defined them: No.

Comment: So, ther would be no problem, because I'm defining and refering them in correct order, in a command, and I would not refer to them so much. I want the list of entries. :-)

Comment: @Ho1: Yes, as long as you do not refer to some other entry (defined later on) in your command.

Comment: I should provide bilingual glossary, so I started using this: http://parsilatex.com/users/diyanat/GlossSample.zip It is really low level, and I can't change it. In this script, you should provide the name and you'll get a footnote on the first call. But I don't like this behaviour.

Comment: I had to add this to get the job done with code from the above sample (mentioned zip file): `\newcommand{\gloss}[2]{%
\newglossaryentry{f-#2}{type={persian},name={#2},text={#1},description={#2}}\glsadd{f-#2}%
\newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#1},text={#1},description={#2}}#1\LTRfootnote{\Glsdesc{#2}}}` It works great, it generates bilingual glossary as it should.

Comment: @Ho1: Yes, but this is another question

Comment: Yeah, sure; It works now, but If I encounter problems, I will ask and request knowldge from great people like you. :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Ho1: As soon as problems occur we from TeX.SX fly by like Superman ;-) Ok, sometimes we cause problems :D